# Octave minimization for a many-body Hamiltonian with non-linear constraint

Tags: optimization, octave, physics, nonlinear-optimization

I work in theoretical physics, and I have come upon a problem that requires the minimization of a particular Hamiltonian operator for a system of 8 particles, with one non-linear constraint. Due to the complexity of the system, I cannot define the entire Hamiltonian "in one go", nor the constraint. By this I mean that the quantity I am searching for is defined recurrently, depending on complex summations over quantities calculated for systems of 7 particles, which in turn depend on quantities calculated for systems of 6, and so on, until it reaches a one or two-particle system, for which said quantities are given as initial values, dependent on the elements of a column vector (the argument/minization parameters). The constraint itself is also of this form, requiring the "overlap" between the states of 8 particles to be exactly 1. (I.E. the state be normalized) I have been thinking of a way to use fmincon for this, but I've come up short, since my function has an implicit dependence on the parameters, and I can't write the whole thing explicitly. For a better understanding, here is some of the code:

```
for m=3:npairs+1
  for n=3:npairs+1
    for i=1:nsps
      for j=1:nsps
        overlap(m,n)=overlap(m,n)+x(i)*x(j)*(delta(i,j)*(overlap(m-1,n-1)-N(m-1,n-1,i))+p0p(m-1,n-1,j,i));
        p(m,n,i)=(n-1)*x(i)*overlap(m,n-1)-(n-2)*(n-1)*x(i)*x(i)*((m-1)*x(i)*overlap(m-1,n-1)-(m-2)*(m-1)*x(i)*x(i)*p(m-1,n-1,i));
        N(m,n,i)=2*(n-1)*x(i)*p(n-1,m,i);
        p0p(m,n,i,j)=(m-1)*(n-1)*x(i)*x(j)*overlap(m-1,n-1)-(m-1)*(n-1)*(m-2)*x(i)*x(i)*x(j)*p(m-2,n-1,i)-(m-1)*(n-1)*(n-2)*x(i)*x(j)*x(j)*p0(m-1,n-2,j)-(m-1)*(n-1)*(m-2)*(n-2)*x(i)*x(i)*x(j)*x(j)*(delta(i,j)*(overlap(m-2,n-2)-N(m-2,n-2,i))+p0p(m-2,n-2,j,i));
      endfor
    endfor
  endfor
endfor

function [E]=H(x)
    E=summation over all i and j of N and p0p for m=n=8 %not actual code


endfunction
overlap(9,9)=1 %constraint
```

Comment: Since this is Octave rather than MATLAB, that tag is more appropriate. It also seems like the sticking point here is the maths; you've tried to define the problem with words but defining it in terms of equations and functions would made the translation to code simpler. "Here is some of the code" doesn't provide much help without context about what this bit of code is trying to do, without any in-line comments about what the variables are, or any info about why this code doesn't achieve what you're asking for.

Comment: @Wolfie I also used the Octave tag, but given this is my first question and the syntax is near identical I thought I would have more chances to get an answer if the question was tagged with both. I apologize if that caused any misunderstanding and will be more careful in the future. Defining the entire problem and the actual meaning of every term in said equation requires quite a bit of knowledge of quantum nuclear theory, and I am not interested in having someone fix the parts already written for me, since I know they are correct. I am only looking to minimize the function with the constraint

Comment: If the question requires background in quantum nuclear theory then a public Q&A site may not be what you need. The bottom line is that you're trying to implement some maths, and haven't provided the equations, which makes it more subjective (based on your description alone)  and harder to answer. If you think the background is beyond us then you need to simplify the problem; an 8 layer recursion could become a 2 layer recursion for the sake of a [mcve], a large system can become a small system, this would also help with your own understanding of your problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to give a specific answer, but I would advise the following to get you started.

First, note that, the inner two steps of the nest loop can be vectorised, since i and j always appear as indices (whereas m and n make backreferences, so they cannot be vectorised). So your 4-level loop can be reduced to a 2-level loop containing 4 functions operating over i-by-j matrices.

Second, note that the whole construct can be expressed as a recursive function. If you have suitable base cases for m = 0, n = 0, you can iteratively obtain all i,j matrices for all cases up to m=9,n=9. In particular, you can try to 'memoize' the early steps, and plug them into higher steps, rather than rely on actual recursion.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need to sum with the first two indeces fixed to 8 (if I understood correctly), you can easily do with `Anonymous Functions`
https://octave.org/doc/v6.1.0/Anonymous-Functions.html#Anonymous-Functions

```
# creating same data
A=ones(8,8,4,4);
B=2*ones(8,8,4,4);

# defining 2 versions of sums
f = @(A,B) [sum(sum(A(8,8,:,:))), sum(sum(B(8,8,:,:)))];
g = @(A,B) sum(sum(A(8,8,:,:)))+ sum(sum(B(8,8,:,:)));

E1=f(A,B)
E2=g(A,B)
```

the output will be:

```
octave:21> E1=f(A,B)
E1 =

   16   32

octave:22> E2=g(A,B)
E2 =  48
```